# Верно ли что при использовании методов массива (pop(), push(), map()), реализуется принцип прототипного наследования?

Tags: javascript

При использовании методов массива (`pop()`, `push()`, `map()`), **реализуется принцип прототипного наследования**, так как массив это объект имеющий прототип Array, который в свою очередь имеет все доступные методы для работы с массивом.

Comment: нет............

Comment: сколько много точек =)
можно узнать почем нет? ведь массив не имеет методов по дефолту, а они наследуются из прототипа Array.prototype

Comment: а почему да? :)

Comment: Вы бы использовали наследование если создали бы `class A extends Array` например

Comment: С ключевым словом extends это понятно, мы в ручную устанавливаем __proto__ у класса A. Но так как Array является встроенным прототипом, возник вопрос, верно ли высказывание что при использовании методов массива реализуется принцип прототипного наследования?

Comment: @Кларк мало ли как объект устроен внутри, Вы не доопределяли его никак чтобы говорить о наследовании

Comment: @Stranger in the Q как тогда можно грамотно назвать принцип работы методов массива в языке?

Comment: @Кларк вопрос ради вопроса? что Вы пытаетесь для себя прояснить?